# How to change settings in "resources" folder?

Tags: java

I want to change the properties file in the "resources" folder when entering the number 1 from the keyboard

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            int a = scanner.nextInt();
            if (a == 1) {
                
            }
```

Code in file properties:

```
my.name=Test
```

I don't understand through which class and method to change the value of the field "my.name"

Comment: You can use `java.util.Properties` to load properties and write them back to a file. However this will not work when you package your properties file into a .jar file (which maven will do with anything inside `src/main/resources`), as everything in it will be read-only.

Comment: If it's a "resource" of *that app* though, it's intended to be read-only

Comment: @f1sh there are definitely some weird hacks for changing jarfile resources on-the-fly, but I don't really recommend them (and any anti-virus program will rightfully lose their mind). @OP Rather, a simpler/more standard way is to use that resource as a "default" file, save it somewhere (e.g. `%APPDATA%` or `~` or `/usr/local/...`), and then save/load/modify/etc that file instead.

Comment: Save the configuration to e.g. `~/.config/`. Windows, Mac, and Linux all have different config locations. This way you can either load the bundled config, or detect a user config and read/write to that. For example, take a look at [JD GUI's config service](https://github.com/java-decompiler/jd-gui/blob/master/app/src/main/java/org/jd/gui/service/configuration/ConfigurationXmlPersisterProvider.java#L30).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a properties file located at: `src/main/resources/default.properties`. The following application will handle loading and saving a user-specific properties file located in their config directory.

This example assumes you have a Maven POM with a structure of:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>java-config</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
  </properties>
</project>
```

#### `src/main/java/org/example/App.java`

The code below is a stripped-down version of JD-GUI's [`ConfigurationXmlPersisterProvider`](https://github.com/java-decompiler/jd-gui/blob/master/app/src/main/java/org/jd/gui/service/configuration/ConfigurationXmlPersisterProvider.java#L30) class. It has been modified to load and save a Java `Properties` object to memory.

In Windows, a config file will be generated under: `%AppData%\app-overrides.properties`

```java
package org.example;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class App {
    // Config override file location
    public static final String CONFIG_FILENAME = "app-overrides.properties";

    protected static final File FILE = getConfigFile();

    // Bundled resource
    private static final String DEFAULT_PROPERTIES_RESOURCE = "/default.properties";
    private static final String PROP_KEY_MY_NAME = "my.name";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Properties props = load();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Show the loaded config
        System.out.printf("Stored: %s%n", props);

        // Override the default config
        System.out.printf("Enter a value for %s: ", PROP_KEY_MY_NAME);
        String newValue = scanner.nextLine();
        props.setProperty(PROP_KEY_MY_NAME, newValue);

        // Update the user config
        save(props);

        scanner.close(); // Always close resources
    }

    protected static File getConfigFile() {
        String configFilePath = System.getProperty(CONFIG_FILENAME);
        if (configFilePath != null) {
            File configFile = new File(configFilePath);
            if (configFile.exists()) {
                return configFile;
            }
        }
        if (PlatformService.getInstance().isLinux()) {
            String xdgConfigHome = System.getenv("XDG_CONFIG_HOME");
            if (xdgConfigHome != null) {
                File xdgConfigHomeFile = new File(xdgConfigHome);
                if (xdgConfigHomeFile.exists()) {
                    return new File(xdgConfigHomeFile, CONFIG_FILENAME);
                }
            }
            File userConfigFile = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), ".config");
            if (userConfigFile.exists()) {
                return new File(userConfigFile, CONFIG_FILENAME);
            }
        } else if (PlatformService.getInstance().isWindows()) {
            String roamingConfigHome = System.getenv("APPDATA");
            if (roamingConfigHome != null) {
                File roamingConfigHomeFile = new File(roamingConfigHome);
                if (roamingConfigHomeFile.exists()) {
                    return new File(roamingConfigHomeFile, CONFIG_FILENAME);
                }
            }
        }
        return new File(CONFIG_FILENAME);
    }

    public static Properties load() {
        // Load the default props for fall-back values
        Properties defaultProps = new Properties();
        try {
            defaultProps.load(App.class.getResourceAsStream(DEFAULT_PROPERTIES_RESOURCE));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Load the stored user overrides
        Properties props = new Properties();
        if (FILE.exists()) {
            try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(FILE)) {
                props.load(fis);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        // If the stored value is undefined, use the default
        String myName = props.getProperty(PROP_KEY_MY_NAME);
        if (myName == null || myName.equals("")) {
            props.setProperty(PROP_KEY_MY_NAME, defaultProps.getProperty(PROP_KEY_MY_NAME));
        }

        return props;
    }

    public static void save(Properties props) {
        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(FILE)) {
            props.store(fos, null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // Based on JD-GUI's org.jd.gui.service.platform.PlatformService
    private static class PlatformService {
        protected static final PlatformService PLATFORM_SERVICE = new PlatformService();

        public enum OS {
            Linux, MacOSX, Windows
        }

        protected final OS os;

        protected PlatformService() {
            os = detectOS();
        }

        public static PlatformService getInstance() {
            return PLATFORM_SERVICE;
        }

        public OS getOs() {
            return os;
        }

        public boolean isLinux() {
            return os == OS.Linux;
        }

        public boolean isMac() {
            return os == OS.MacOSX;
        }

        public boolean isWindows() {
            return os == OS.Windows;
        }

        private static OS detectOS() {
            String osName = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase(Locale.US);
            if (osName.contains("windows")) {
                return OS.Windows;
            } else if (osName.contains("mac os")) {
                return OS.MacOSX;
            } else {
                return OS.Linux;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use java.util.Properties

```
FileReader reader = new FileReader("Config.properties");
        
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.load(reader);
```

now you can get value based on key from prop object and change it and write back to file

Comment: As noted in the comments, this will not work for saving that same resource back to the jarfile.